# How to load html onto a page after it is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, once someone clicks a button a new page is opened (it is about:blank), using this code

```html
<img src="sits_01.png" width="180" height="35" onclick="var x = window.open('', '', 'location=no,toolbar=0');
x.document.body.innerHTML = CONTENT;">
```

Once this is done, I want an entire html file to be loaded onto the page.  How would I go about doing this?  I'm pretty new to web development so don't get to technical please and thank you.

Comment: You should just specify the URL to open the window at.  No need to inject data into the DOM yourself.

Comment: I suggest you to learn more about Javascript and Web development, because there is some errors in your syntaxes